# How do I write this graphQL query

Tags: graphql

I am trying to use this api https://rapidapi.com/whatsong-whatsong-default/api/soundtrack-playlists/ for my movie soundtrack app but I am unfamiliar with graphQL querying.  Can someone give an example for how you would query the soundtrack of a movie by the movie's name like the soundtrack for the movie "Titanic". Thank you!

Comment: Please read [Query and Mutations part](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#the-query-and-mutation-types).

Comment: I have read through the documentation and I am still very confused.  It would be helpful to see an example using my specific API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which query you want to execute. Here it goes a example of querying the field `SpotifyTracks`:

```
query {
  SpotifyTracks (q: "Titanic") {
    tracks {
      items {
        name
        album
        uri
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also pass the `variables` separately, which would result in a query like this:

```
query ($movieName: String!){
  SpotifyTracks (q: $movieName) {
    tracks {
      items {
        name
        album
        uri
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then pass the variable `movieName` separately.

Comment: This is really helpful thank you!